# After Ubuntu crash, can't open Audacity as "already running"

Tags: crash, audacity

While converting some audio in Audacity, I moved by accident the file Audacity that was exporting.

As the file was still being exported, the system crashed.

After reboot, if I try to open Audacity,its dialog window goes like there was already am open session of Audacity:

```
The system has detected that another copy of Audacity is running.
Running two copies of Audacity simultaneously may cause
data loss or cause your system to crash.

Use the New or Open commands in the currently running Audacity
process to open multiple projects simultaneously.
```

Of course, I can't see any open Audacity.

Is there a way to kill an "invisible" session of Audacity, or maybe is there any system file to analyse as the software process is not active in system monitor?

Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
rm -f /var/tmp/audacity-$USER/audacity-lock-$USER
```

And try to open Audacity.

Comment: mhm, after killing the process in the system monitor+reboot it's working again. Now I read your answer... So I can't try your solution. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
exec sudo -i
rm -f /var/tmp/audacity-$USER/audacity-lock-$USER
```

And try to open Audacity.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, this does not answer the Question, this is same as @kyodake Solution. Feel Free to take a [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) of the Site. If Someone answer helps you, than you can thanks him by up-voting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing this file

```
~/.audacity-data/audacity.cfg
```

The other solutions here didn't work for me.

When I reopened Audacity, I noticed that there was an unsaved project I hadn't closed properly.

This is with Audacity 2.1.2 On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a general solution, which might be more intuitive for someone. This problem appears when Audacity is not closed properly. Therefore, an old lock file is still present which doesn't let Audacity to start another instance. The issue can be fixed by finding the location of this lock file and deleting it. In Ubuntu, the location of lock file can be seen in

> `~/.audacity-data/audacity.cfg`

The configuration file lists a `TempDir` underneath `[Directories]` subheading. For me, it is `/var/tmp/audacity-$USER`

Change directory to this folder, and delete the lock file named as `audacity-lock-$USER`.

Now, Audacity will open.